# Building iPhone Code using xcodebuild and running LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, static-analysis, clang

I followed the steps in *[Finding memory leaks with the LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer](https://web.archive.org/web/20111129115318/http://fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2008/08/finding-memory-leaks-with-the-llvmclang-static-analyzer/)* but I was unable to run static analyzer on my project.

When I try to run `xcodebuild` on my project (1. Open Terminal, 2. Go to Project Directly, 3. > xcodebuild), I get this error:

```
=== BUILDING NATIVE TARGET XProject OF PROJECT XProject WITH THE DEFAULT
CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Checking Dependencies... CodeSign
error: no certificate found in
keychain for code signing identity
'iPhone Developer'

\** BUILD FAILED \**
```

How can I run this tool on my code? - I'm testing with simulator. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is here:
[Using the LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer for iPhone apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20100309124345/http://www.oiledmachine.com/posts/2009/01/06/using-the-llvm-clang-static-analyzer-for-iphone-apps.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the blog post that you reference in your question.  If codelogic's comments are not enough to point you in the right direction you can wait until a bit later today and I will update the blog post with some more information about running xcodebuild against iPhone projects.

-- Michael

--

Alright, I've updated the post with a section titled **iPhone Usage**.  Hope this helps!

[Finding Memory Leaks With The LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer](https://web.archive.org/web/20111129115318/http://fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2008/08/finding-memory-leaks-with-the-llvmclang-static-analyzer/)

Comment: I just checked the post and its still the same. Detail on how to use xcodebuild against iPhone projects (with no certificate - testing on simulator) would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the tool in question but the issue you're seeing appears to be a bothced xcodebuild command. Ensure that your target is the Simulator and not the device (-target command line argument).

Comment: Can you please elaborate (explain a little, target is set to simulator and i'm testing my application on simulator using xcode).

Comment: You need to pass the target to the xcodebuild command line. Open Terminal and type xcodebuild --help to see the available options.

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange but I've switched active Configuration to **Debug** **EVERYWHERE** but  still got same error (like Release is active). Xcode 3.1.3 version.

I was able to fix problem just after **removing Release configuration**  at all from active target.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to set the base sdk.  I like this approach:

[image]

I would have sworn that I had already set the sdk via the more traditional 'Build' tab, but hey...  The 'Build' tab approach failed me (who know what I did wrong), but this worked great.

Good luck.

[Edit - I just visited the link posted in the Question - which repeats, but does not emphasize, what I'm claiming here.]